# What problems to expect with Dell G5 15 5500 and how to solve them?

Tags: dual-boot, dell, ssd, rst

I want to make Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot on my machine, but I'm not sure, what problems may I face and how to solve them. I have Dell G5 15 5500 laptop with Micron 2300 NVMe 1024GB SSD. I found it as [Certified Hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202001-27694), but I'm not sure that it's the exact same model. When I try to install Ubuntu, I run into a problem with Intel RST. [You can find the configuration here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-ZHliOGQxV045UndlSktPVzFaaGVhdz090/upgrade#).

I was searching for some guides and help, but I have more questions about this, so I'm asking here.

Will I be able to get dual-boot and not lose my data? If I won't be able to get dual-boot, could I run only Ubuntu? Won't there be problems about the NVMe SSD or Nvidia graphics card?

I already installed Ubuntu on desktop, but with laptop I have no Windows CD to reinstall my system.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm sure that at least Ubuntu 18.04 LTS works with the Dell G5 15 5500.** Because another version, the Dell G5 5500 came preinstalled with Ubuntu (see [here](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202001-27694)), the same will go for this one. You can install it, it's 95% verified to work on your system.

Edit: About the RST situation, you should look [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!